# Plupload, установить минимальный размер файла

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, yii

добрый день, есть проект на yii1, в нём реализована загрузка файлов на сервер при помощи js библиотеки [plupload](http://www.plupload.com). Мне нужно установить минимальный размер загружаемого файла, пользователем, в документации не смог найти как задать такой параметр. Может кто-то знает как решить такую задачу? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Если расширение использует CUploadedFile, то смотрите [CUploadedFile::getSize()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile#getSize-detail)
иначе $_FILES